# New thread every n minutes (java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method))

Tags: java, glassfish

I read all existing topics but I didn't find any solution to my problem. I monitor my glassfish server with VisualVM and I have noticed some strange behaviour. Here is screenshot:

[image]

```
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for <3cb9965d> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

As you can see new thread is created every 20 minutes (next one, Thread-38 will be created and then Thread-39 and so on). These threads are never finished. I am using newSingleThreadExecutor() from class Executors which is scheduled with scheduleWithFixedDelay() with 100 ms delay, other code is just DB read/write (so nothing special that would create new waiting threads)... Does someone have any idea what may be causing this problem?

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //do something...
            }
        }, 1, readInterval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

EDIT: new threads are created every 20 minutes even no applications are deployed to server. Did anybody notice similar problems? I also noticed that all newly threads are waiting for same ID (in this example <3cb9965d>)...

Comment: Hi, is there any synchronisation in your code?

Comment: Hi, no synchronisation.

Comment: This happens even if no application is deployed on glassfish server (running only glassfish). I checked all setting and I did not find anything that could cause this problem. It's still creating new Thread every 20minutes and waits forever....

Comment: You say that you're using `newSingleThreadExecutor()`. Exactly how are you using it?

Comment: I added an example of using it in my post. But like i said - new thread is generated every 20min even no application in deployed to server (running just glassfish)!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your observation reflects the behaviour of the thread-pool...

If a thread has been idle for a certain time in the thread-pool **it will be removed from the thread-pool**.

Depending on your settings in glassfish's domain.xml **a new thread will be created** to meet the minimum amount of threads in the pool. *Please note that glassfish uses its own default values if you do not specify them in the domain.xml-file.*

The threads have all the same ID because **they belong to the same thread-pool**.

To verify that you can add the attribute *idle-thread-timeout-seconds="300"* to the *http-thread-pool* in the domain.xml and check it again with VisualVM.

```html
 <thread-pool idle-thread-timeout-seconds="300" name="http-thread-pool"></thread-pool>
```

The above sets the timeout for idle threads to 5 minutes. Maybe you find "idle-thread-timeout-seconds="1200" somewhere in your domain.xml, this would explain the 20 minutes intervall you observed...

***Further Explanation:***

If you take a look at the domain.xml you might find following entries (yours might be different...):

```html
   [...]

<!-- HTTP -->
<network-listener protocol="http-listener-1" port="8080" 
    name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool" 
    transport="tcp"></network-listener>
<!--HTTPS -->
<network-listener protocol="http-listener-2" port="8181" 
   name="http-listener-2" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"
   transport="tcp"></network-listener>
   [...]

<!--Threadpools wich can be used by network-listeners-->
<thread-pools>
    <thread-pool name="admin-thread-pool" max-queue-size="256" max-thread-pool-size="50"></thread-pool>
    <thread-pool name="http-thread-pool"></thread-pool>
    <thread-pool name="thread-pool-1" max-thread-pool-size="200"></thread-pool>
  </thread-pools>

[...]
```

As you can see there are no attributes specified for the thread-pool **"http-thread-pool"**. This means that galssfish will use its own default values.

The default values for the "http-thread-pool" in my glassfish installation (4.1) have follwoing values*:

- Max Queue Size: 4096
- Max Thread Pool Size: 5
- Min Thread Pool Size: 5
- Idle Thread Timeout: 900 (seconds)

In this case, if a thread has been idle for 15 minutes, it will be removed from the thread pool. Due to the value of "Min Thread Pool Size = 5" a new thread will be created if the number of threads goes below five.

*You can go to the Admin console of glassfish and open 
 "Configurations -> server-config -> Thread pools" to find out your default values.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried with this settings but threads are still created every 20 min. I also checked if there si number 1200 anywhere but I didn't find it anywhere. Have you noticed same behaviour on your server or yours works fine? Anyway can you please explain me what are recommended setting for Max/Min Thread Pool Size for http-thread-pool (is 5 enough)?