# Glassfish/JVM production configuration

Tags: java, glassfish, jvm

I found this article (besides many other): https://open.bekk.no/glassfish-production-tuning

I want to know if these settings are fine and what else do I need to change/add or I have to be careful of (glassfish and jvm settings)? I have been using default settings during development and now I don't know if these setting are ok...

Comment: It's very likely that `-Xmx1024m` will be not enough for production

Comment: Try to summarize the article you have shared within the question. It will be more readable and it is more likely to get the correct answer.

Comment: Anyway, server configuration is a very complicated topic, and no one here can help you without knowing about hardware configuration, apps you intend to use there, other software installed and used on that machine etc. Optimal JVM and server configuration will depend on many many things

Comment: Thank you. Server would be PC with i7-4770 (3.4GHz) and 8GB of RAM because it would have only one internal (company) web application (maximum 10 client connection at a time). I read a lot of articles but none of them show me how to correctly calculate xmx,... depending on system configuration.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments the tuning of the jvm and memory is a complicated topic.

The server performance depends a lot on what technologies and libraries you use and how you use them. E.g. Do you use a database? And if, how do you connect and access the DB... just to mention a few impact factors...

From my expierence I can say that more memory **will not protect you from web application failure** if you have some memory leaks caused by e.g. open DB connections or growing session size after a certain time in production.

I do not know which kind of application it is and what technologies you use, so I will give you a general aproach...

**Approach to find the values for JVM and Glassfish:**

I would recommend you to run a load test with e.g. jmeter and monitor the garbage collection and memory usage of your application.

Also **check the size of the user sessions in glassfish during the tests** from time to time and check if they grow bigger.

A possible test plan might look like this:

- First Test: short term invervall (one day) and five users
- Second Test: short term invervall (one day) and ten users

if the above tests pass:

- Thrid Test: longer term invervall (3-5 days) and five users
- Fourth Test: longer term invervall (3-5 days) and ten users

Depending on the result should have some indicators for the galssfish and JVM parameter values. This lets you adjust the settings for memory, garbage collection and so on to your needs.

This article will give you some hints what you might expect in production enviornment:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/top-10-causes-java-ee

Comment: Thank you. I would also ask you to look at this topic if you know how to solve this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030271/new-thread-every-n-minutes-java-lang-thread-state-waiting-at-sun-misc-unsafe-p#